# Does Task Runner Explorer support CI build servers?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I recently learned of [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) and am curious about it's capabilities. I use TeamCity and AppVeyor in my work and I'm wondering how it plays with CI tools. I took a quick look and can't see any targets added to my project's `.csproj` file.

Is there a quick and happy way to take advantage of these event hooks in a build environment outside of the IDE?

Comment: As far as I can see no it is Visual Studio only. There is a comment in the Q and A by Mads Kristensen dated Sep 15 2014 that CI support is coming. At the moment I'm using a command in a MSBuild pre-build event.
https://www.vsgallery.net/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708/view/Discussions/9#!

Comment: We use Task Runner Explorer locally. We have separate build steps in Team City to run grunt and gulp, it might? be nice to have a one-stop place to configure this for both local and CI builds

Comment: We've found Task Runner Explorer in VS2017 to be unreliable. eg: first-run after checkout fails, node modules sometimes need manually deleting, etc. So I wouldn't like that happening on the CI server.